# How to insert variables into search engines

Tags: php

I'm developing a web application where the user can enter text into an input and the user input is saved into a variable.

-This variable is then inserted into a search engine of another external webpage (i suppose that the easy method is with the 'id' of the search input)

-Then the submit button of the search engine is actuated

Thanks in advance. All purposes will be studied ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm telling you that my english is poor, and you decided to close the question instead of trying to help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want an external search engine to do your work for you its pretty easy. Take the variable from the user and append it to the following string

```
google.ca/search?q=
```

So lets say the user searches for cats; the following will be your string:

```
google.ca/search?q=cats
```

Then you can just redirect the user by either using the php [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) or by making that string into a link and placing it on the page. Hope this helps.